# subprocess stdout string decoding not working

Tags: string, python-3.x, utf-8, subprocess, ascii

I'm using the following subprocess call to use a command line tool. The output of the command line tool isn't printed in one go, it prints immediately on the command line, it generates over multiple lines over a period of time. The tool is [bs1770gain](http://bs1770gain.sourceforge.net/) and the command would be "path\to\bs1770gain.exe" "-i" "\path\to\audiofile.wav", By using the --loglevel parameter you can include more data but you cannot remove the progressive results being written to stdout.

I need stdout to return a human readable string (hence the stdout_formatted operation):

```
with subprocess.Popen(list_of_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    stdout_formatted = stdout.decode('UTF-8')
    stderr_formatted = stderr.decode('UTF-8')
```

However I can only view the variable as a human readable string if I print it e.g.

```
In [23]: print(stdout_formatted )
      nalyzing ...   [1/2] "filename.wav": 
          integrated:  -2.73 LUFS / -20.27 LU   [2/2] 
      "filename2.wav":         
          integrated:  -4.47 LUFS / -18.53 LU   
      [ALBUM]:
          integrated:  -3.52 LUFS / -19.48 LU done.

In [24]: stdout_formatted 
Out[24]: 'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00g\.......

In [6]: stdout
Out[6]: b'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00g\......

In [4]: type(stdout)
Out[4]: bytes

In [5]: type(stdout_formatted)
Out[5]: str
```

If you look carefully, the human readable chars are in the string (the first word is "analyzing"

I guessed that the stdout value needs decoding/encoding so I tried different ways:

```
stdout_formatted.encode("ascii")
Out[18]: b'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00g

stdout_formatted.encode("utf-8")
Out[17]: b'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00g\

stdout.decode("utf-8")
Out[15]: 'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00g\

stdout.decode("ascii")
Out[14]: 'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00g\

bytes(stdout).decode("ascii")
Out[13]: 'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00g\
```

I used a library called chardet to check the encoding of stdout:

```
import chardet

chardet.detect(stdout)
Out[26]: {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii', 'language': ''}
```

I'm working on Windows 10 and have am using python  3.6 (the anaconda package and it's integrated Spyder IDE).

I'm kind of clutching at straws now - is it possible to capture what is displayed in the console when print is called in a variable or remove the unwanted bytecode in the stdout string?

Comment: You show the `type` of `stdout`, but printouts of `stderr`.  Do you see the same problem for both kinds of output?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - there were some typos in the code (which I've fixed now). I am focusing on stdout as there are no outputs on stderr until now. It is simply a blank string '' of type string.

Comment: Could you provide that `list_of_args` so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have UTF-8 data. You have UTF-16 data. UTF-16 uses *two* bytes for every character; characters in the ASCII and Latin-1 ranges (such as `a`), still use 2 bytes, but one of those bytes is always a `\x00` NUL byte.

Because UTF-16 always uses 2 bytes for every character, their order starts to matter. Encoders can pick between the two options; one is called [Little Endian, the other Big Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Normally, encoders then include a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the very start, so that the decoder knows which of the two order options to use when decoding.

Your posted data doesn't appear to include the BOM (I don't see the `0xFF` and `0xFE` bytes, but your data does look like it is using little-endian ordering. That fits with this being Windows; Windows always uses little-endian ordering for it's UTF-16 output.

If your data does have the BOM present, you can just decode as `'utf-16'`. If the BOM is missing, use `'utf-16-le'`:

```
>>> sample = b'a\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00'
>>> sample.decode('utf-16-le')
'analyzin'
>>> import codecs
>>> (codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE + sample)
b'\xff\xfea\x00n\x00a\x00l\x00y\x00z\x00i\x00n\x00'
>>> (codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE + sample).decode('utf-16')
'analyzin'
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the detailed answer - it explains a lot. The string output still includes (for lack of a better word) "gibberish" between the human readable strings which have been correctly decoded. The cmd line tool (bs1770gain http://bs1770gain.sourceforge.net/ - "path\to\bs1770gain.exe" "-i" "\path\to\audiofile.wav" would be an example of how I'm calling it from the cmd line)  doesn't return a single string of results but kind of generates it during its processing cycle. It seems the "gibbierish" is everything between each line of output.

Comment: @user3535074: the gibberish is almost certainly a progressbar, involving writing out a percentage, then using the carriage return character (`\r`) to move back the cursor position for the next update to overwrite the old status.

Comment: Any tips on removing the gibberish? I checked the tool parameters and saw no option to return a final bare bones results string

Comment: @user3535074 I'm not familiar with the tool. Online info suggests the `loglevel` option might be something to look into. There's a XML output option too.

Comment: @user3535074: I took a look at the code some more and I'm pretty sure the `--xml` option replaces the progress-bar output entirely with machine-parsable XML. At that point you could just use an XML parser to parse the bytestream; as far as I can see the code produces ASCII-safe XML (but do watch out for the UTF-16 encoding still being present).

Comment: You're right! Adding the --xml parameter returns the results as xml without the gibberish. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good explanation. But your statement, that utf-16 is always using 2 bytes is not correct. From character 000000-00fffff, it uses 2 bytes. From 010000-10FFFF it uses 4 bytes. See: [Comparison of Unicode encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings)

Comment: @SimonLang: it uses **two codepoints**, each codepoint is 2 bytes. Surrogate pairs are still valid UTF-16 codepoints, in that they each consist of a 2-byte value. See the [*U+10000 to U+10FFFF* section of the Wikipedia UTF-16 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+10000_to_U+10FFFF).

Comment: @MartijnPieters To be honest, I did not look that deep into how UTF-16 encodes values >=U+10000. Interesting though. Thank you for the link. But it still, for characters from "Supplementary Planes", it needs 2 times 2-bytes. Else it is unable to encode it to binary form. No? Maybe it is more a philosophical discussion.

Comment: @SimonLang it is not just philosophical. Many programming languages model Unicode text as UTF-16 codepoint sequences, and the length of a non-BMP Unicode string is twice as long because surrogate codepoints are counted separately. This includes Python 2 (at least, with the default UCS-2 compile-time switch, there is a UCS-4 option).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the progress information added by `bs1770gain`. It is not said in the man page but there is a "--suppress-progress" flag !

So I just use this command line and everythig were OK ;)

```
bs1770gain --xml --suppress-progress "$filename"
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried :

```
 str(stdout_formatted).replace('\x00','')
```

?

Comment: Yeah, afraid it doesn't fix the string. Instead of \x00 I get this instead "0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%1%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2%2"

Comment: @user3535074: that looks like something is printing a progress bar. Exactly what command are you running? Can you disable the progress information?

Comment: The output of the command line tool isn't printed in one go, it prints one line, then the next. The tool is bs1770gain and the command would be "path\to\bs1770gain.exe" "-i" "\path\to\audiofile.wav"

Comment: @user3535074 you might wanna add this to your question rather than in the comments so everyone could see it.

Comment: @user3535074 also you could remove that percentage part with re: `your_string = re.sub(r'\d+%','',your_string)`

Comment: Thanks - added the tool/parameters to the question. For the re solution, it doesn't work. I think the problem is that its not really a string which can be operated on like a normal string.

Comment: @user3535074: it's a perfectly normal string. There are control codes between those digits and percent characters too; use `repr()` to inspect the string so the control codes are shown as `\xhh` or `\l` escape codes. A regex that ignores those codes is likely to fail.