# How to get audiocards models and names in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, hardware

I need to get audiocards models and names in Python on Windows, but i didn't find anything about it on internet

Comment: What is meant by "audiocards models"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you will have to use wmic and get data.  Following is  a sample code that will give you  the output

```
from subprocess import run
out =  run ([ "wmic",  "sounddev", "get",  "Name" "/format:list"], capture_output=True)
my_list = out.stdout.decode().split("\n")
name_list = [name.split("Name=")[1]  for name in my_list  if "Name" in name]
print(name_list)
```

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\camil\Desktop\lol.py", line 4, in <module>
    my_list = out.stdout.decode().split("\n")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 54: invalid start byte```

Comment: Looks like your  data encoding is encoding is utf-16  or utf-16-le
can you try
my_list = out.stdout.decode("utf-16").split("\n")
and if it does not work
my_list = out.stdout.decode("utf-16-le").split("\n")
read  this too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909639/subprocess-stdout-string-decoding-not-working#45988346\